# RethinkDB - Integer Increment in Document (Python)

Tags: python, rethinkdb

How can I perform a simple integer increment in a document (if there is any)? I tried `r.db("test").get(id).update({"views":r.row.add(1)}).run()` and it does not work.

Currently I am doing this way:

```
m = r.db("test").get(id).run()
r.db("test").get(id).update({"views":m["views"]+1}).run()
```

If there is a one-liner solution would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
r.table("posts").get(1).update({
    views: r.row["views"].add(1)
})
```

You're doing `r.row.add` but you need to choose which field to increment (`views` in this case). So you have to do `r.row["<fieldname>"].add(1)`

Comment: i got error r.row is not callable, use r.row[...] instead

Comment: got it fixed, it needs to be done this way `r.table("posts").get(1).update({
    views: r.row["views"].add(1)
})`

Comment: I am updating the answer.